# How to parse XML using SAX2DOM and Tagsoup in Coldfusion

Tags: java, xml, coldfusion

I am working on scrapping an html file using the SAX2DOM and Tagsoup library as mention in Ben Nadel's post [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2341-coldfusion-10-parsing-dirty-html-into-valid-xml-documents.htm). I have been running the exact same code as mentioned in the post.

However I have been getting this error:

> Unable to make public com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM(org.w3c.dom.Node,boolean) throws javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException accessible: module java.xml does not "exports com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax" to unnamed module.

Is there anyway to resolve this? Is the use of this library deprecated? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Java no longer allow direct access to internal private classes like `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM`.

You'll probably find there is an equivalent public class in the version of Xalan obtainable from apache.org.